# I am going to Mexico from Canada for 7 days. My passport expires in less than two months. Is that ok?

Tags: canada, mexico, passport-renewals

I am Canadian, travelling to Mexico for seven days. My passport will expire less than three months. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

> My passport will expire less than three months. Is that a problem?

No, based on the information found on both the *Embassy of Mexico in Canada* and *Government of Canada* sites your passport must only be valid at the time of entry and during the period you wish to be in Mexico.

You must, however, apply for a **FMM** (or the new **Electronic Multiple Migratory Form for Air Travel** (FMME Aérea)) beforhand and print the form before entering Mexico.

See the *Embassy of Mexico in Canada* linked below for further details which contains a link to apply for the new **FMME Aérea**.

---

> [2023-11-28: Visas and Services for Foreigners - Embassy of Mexico in Canada](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/canada/index.php/en/consular-services/visas-and-services-for-foreigners)
> The Embassy of Mexico in Canada informs the public that Canadian nationals and permanent residents of Canada do not require a visa to enter Mexico.
>
> Canadian nationals must present a **valid passport to prove their nationality**. Mexican authorities **do not require a minimum period of validity of passports**; nevertheless, this document **must be valid at the time of entry and during the period you wish to be in Mexico**.
>
> Permanent residents of Canada must present their Permanent Resident Card and one of the following documents: valid Passport or Refugee Travel Document.
>
> ---
>
> [Travel advice and advisories for Mexico - Government of Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/mexico)
> **Regular Canadian passport**
> Your passport must be valid for the expected duration of your stay in Mexico.